# GitHub but large files go to Google Drive

Tags: git, github, google-drive-api, git-lfs

I'm working on a unity game with other team members. I'm currently using git lfs but the 1gb it provides to us is definately not enough for the large art assests that we have and the constant changes that are being made to them. I'm looking for an alternative that has the simplicity of using github desktop to push and pull changes but has atleast 10gb of storage. I have a zero budget unfortunately. I was thinking that instead of git lfs pushing to github.com maybe it can push to google drive which gives you 15gb worth of free storage. I do not know if this is possible to do with github desktop or with another client. My team members and I are very new to git so detailed explanations are appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: if you require more storage then GitLab is the best alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [dvc](https://dvc.org/). It's similar to Git LSF and they support google drive as backend.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab may be an alternative to github as it gives you a 10 Gb limit per repo

Comment: gitlab does not have a client. My team member find it hard to use the cli interface. They barely get by with the github client.

Comment: you can use any kind of git gui clients with gitlab. For example: sourcetree, gitkraken (paid), gitExtensions

Comment: I use sourcetree, it's easy to use actually

Comment: thanks a lot! Gitlab works great and I'm using the github client as my team knows (somewhat) how to use it. 
How do I delete older commits on gitlab so save space? Or is that not necessary?

Comment: It's not necesary, but if your really want to do that you can try deleting the .gti folder and start a new repo

Answer (score 0):

Git LFS supports the concepts of [custom transfer adapters and standalone transfer adapters](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/custom-transfers.md).  Those are tools that can upload and download data from an arbitrary location or URL of your choosing, including Google Drive.  Git LFS itself uses these techniques to implement transfers for local paths and `file:///` URLs.

You could create one of these types of adapters to upload your data to Google Drive if you'd like.  You can see what the [local path transfer adapter looks like](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tree/main/lfshttp/standalone) and base it off that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the solution that I use that works fine for me. I do NOT use any version control on any large assets packages that I use in my project. The rest of my project uses Git with BitBucket. I simply put the large assets in a folder that is Untracked.
There is a free software called [FreeFileSync](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20file%20sync%20download&oq=free%20file%20sync&aqs=edge.1.69i57j0i512l7.5577j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which can synchronize across folders on my computer. I use this to clone my untracked folder to another folder elsewhere on my computer. I synchronize this each time I end a session of work. This way I save on uploading large files which can eat up data rather quickly if you are putting large files on a cloud drive.